# How to autoresize ios's view when I set status bar to hidden or not hidden

Tags: iphone, ios, statusbar, resize

When I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:__ animated:__]` to hide the status bar, I got a white space at the top of screen. I know it is for status bar. And if I just use a simple `UIViewController` as my main view controller I could set the view's frame to `(0, 0, 320, 480)` to cover the white sapce. But when I use `UINavigationController`, I don't know how to do that.

Anyone know this? Just give some advice if you don't have time to write code. I could use the advice you provided to do some research.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you will have to access the view of the currentViewController in your UINavigationController and modify that views frame.

```
NSArray *controllers = [navController viewControllers];

// loop through and find the controller you want

// controller.frame.size.height= newHeight
```

You might need to change the view size of the root view controller too.